# How to search for a string in all columns of a table?

Tags: postgresql, string-searching

I use postgresql database and the need is to return all the rows that contain a given string in any column of that table. For example, I have a table like this.

[image]

I need a query to return all rows that has Italy in any of their columns i.e the query shoud return 1st and 3rd rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an IN condition for that:

```
select *
from the_table
where 'Italy' IN (name, native, place);
```